# I'm trying to make a simple loop and it crashes every time I run it

Tags: ios, nstimer

```
- (IBAction) goStrobe:(id) sender {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(runLoop:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void) runLoop {
    if (imageTwo.hidden = YES) {
        imageTwo.hidden = NO;
    }

    if (imageTwo.hidden = NO) {
        imageTwo.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

My code is above.  Every time I trigger goStrobe, it crashes and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Note that your `if` conditions are assignment expressions `=` instead of comparisons `==`. You want the latter.

Comment: And something like: imageTwo.hidden = !imageTwo.hidden would do the same job in one line.

Comment: Related: Not only are you assigning instead of comparing, but also the structure makes your if-clauses ineffective. If the first condition is met you update that value which would then ensure that the second condition is met. So you'd end up in the state before the first if clause.

Answer (score 3):

It's your runLoop function signature which is wrong in the selector, just remove the ":" at the end. You don't need this because your function does not take any parameters.

Comment: +1 but the selector must be `-(void)runLoop:(NSTimer*)timer`.

Comment: @Deepak not necessarily: It's valid to setup `NSTimer` with a selector that takes no arguments — although I normally wouldn't do so.

Comment: @danyowdee But the [`doc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) is precise with the wordings even though the other might work.